# Looking at the next node satisfying an XPATH to define behavior

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, restructuredtext

I'm currently writing a XSLT document to transform javadoc XML output(which isn't modifiable) to restructured text. One of the issues I'm having is the javadoc will have XML with a structure like such

```
<node1>
   <node2>
       <code/>
   </node2>

   <node3>
      <![CDATA[DataType]]>
   </node3>
</node1>

<node1>
   <node3>
      <![CDATA[s need special formatting, but breaks in restructured text]]>
   </node3>
</node1>
```

This produces the ASCII output(the existence of `node2/code` inside of `node1` signifies it should be surrounded with ``)

```
``DataType``s need special formatting, but break in restructured text
```

In restructured text, the closing `` can't be followed by an alphanumeric or it won't render properly, so instead of the previous output, I need to be able to see if the next node matching `//node1/node3` doesn't have it's first character as an alphanumeric, and if it does it delimits it like such

```
``DataType``\s need special formatting, but breaks in restructured text
```

But if it's punctuation, the following is fine

```
``DataType``. need special formatting, but breaks in restructured text
```

Is this possible with XSLT2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be easier to do a "look-behind" rather than trying to look ahead, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="node1/node3" priority="1">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node1[node2/code]/node3" priority="2">
  <xsl:text>``</xsl:text>
  <xsl:next-match />
  <xsl:text>``</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<!-- special template for the block immediately following a node2/code block -->
<xsl:template match="node1[preceding-sibling::node1[1]/node2/code]/node3" priority="3">
  <xsl:if test="matches(., '^[A-Za-z0-9]')">\</xsl:if>
  <xsl:next-match />
</xsl:template>
```

You can even merge the `if` into the match expression

```
<xsl:template match="node1[preceding-sibling::node1[1]/node2/code]
                     /node3[matches(., '^[A-Za-z0-9]')]" priority="3">
  <xsl:text>\</xsl:text>
  <xsl:next-match />
</xsl:template>
```